# How to add specific module in ways that lspconfig can recognise it?

Tags: neovim, lsp, pyright

I have a project that is structured something like this

```
--project_name
|- bin/main.py
|- some_module
    |- file_a.py
    |- file_b.py
    |- ...
|- .vscode/launch.json
```

```python
import sys
from some_module.file_a import func

print("\n".join(sys.path))

print(func())
```

I use `nvim` with `lspconfig` and `dap`/`dap-python` for development/debugging. I have a `launch.json`, which configures the debugging of the project for `dap-python`. It looks something like this

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Main.py",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}:${env:PYTHONPATH}"},
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/main.py"
        }
    ]
}
```

Assuming I am in the `project_name` directory and run `vim .` and then open `bin/main.py` I can set breakpoints and debug as one would expect. Also, if I print the `PYTHONPATH`, everything has been adjusted as per the `launch.json` file.

The problem is that `pyright` is complaining about the import statement `from some_module.file_a import func`. It says `MissingImport`. My `lspconfig.lua` looks like this

```lua
local capabilities = vim.lsp.protocol.make_client_capabilities()

local servers = { "pyright", ... }

for _, lsp in ipairs(servers) do
    require("lspconfig")[lsp].setup {
        on_attach = on_attach,
        capabilities = capabilities,
    }
end
```

Is there an easy way to adjust the `lspconfig` for `pyright` in such a way that it looks for modules anywhere in the current-working-directory and all of its subdirectories?